# Change Windows 10 wallpaper programmatically (Restricted using 'Active Desktop Wallpaper in Group Policy')

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

To be sincere, in my company system changing the wallpaper has been restricted. They have put up a black screen as wallpaper, so whenever I open up the system it feels like am in a dead place.

I think they are using 'Active Desktop Wallpaper in Group Policy' for restricting the wallpaper change. First of all, am just curious to know whether it is possible and is there a way to override this programmatically? I don't need full code, some pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no (unless you have admin rights). At the one place I worked that pushed wallpaper to client machines, there was a very clear entry in the employee handbook that trying to change the wallpaper was a violation of policy (and remember, having a different wallpaper is something that stands out)

Comment: As far as I know, from Win7 on the policy is not just overwriting some local registry settings, but it is stored in separate sections of the registry. In the resulting settings, these are merged and the policy always wins.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the wallpaper if it was restricted in the windows group policy, this applies to all windows version, including Windows 10, any attempts of trying to change it via winapi functions will result in failure, and changing the GP using a non-administrator account is not possible.

Also, sins you said that this is in the company for which you work I suggest staying away from any attempts of changing it as you may get into trouble.

> Just something that I **wouldn't recommend** but is kind of possible

*There is a way tho to not really change the wallpaper but instead create a type of overlay which will put a image in front of the wallpaper while still having files and folders be top most, a good example of this is Wallpaper Engine, but I wouldn't recommend doing this either, because, just like attempting to change the actual wallpaper, it may result in you getting into trouble.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to change the wallpaper by a windows policy, nothing can allow you to do it.

Any WinAPI will refuse to do that.

As I know.